# VS 2010 installed but i have share point server 2010 in my remote machine

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have VS 2010 installed and i have share point server 2010 in my remote machine. So is it possible to do share point 2010 development in VS 2010 without having share point 2010 server on same machine?? Currently it is prompting me and giving message that share point server should be installed. Is there any hack to get out of this.

Thanks in advance !!

--Raghav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not do the development unless untill you have visual studio installed on server hosting SharePoint. You can use Window7 or Windows 2008 server with sharepoint installed on them

Comment: Yep. We all wish it wasn't this way, but it isn't in the cards. Maybe for version 16.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you won't be able to use the tooling in Visual Studio. You'll have to build, deploy and test everything manually.

Instructions on how to do this can be found in Chapter 2 of Inside SharePoint Foundation 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798298.aspx#InsideSP14_Ch2_DSS

If you wish to use the Visual Studio 2010 tooling for SharePoint development, you'll need to install SharePoint 2010 on your development box. Instructions on how to do so can be found here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx